# class pdo not found ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laravel, pdo, ubuntu-20.04

I just upgraded my ubuntu server from 18.04lts to ubuntu20.04. Everything looks fine, but I keep getting this error "class PDO not found" in Laravel application. I just don't get how to install pdo class. Please help

Comment: check if PDO is intalled. If not install pdo extension.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/824485/how-to-activate-php7-0-pdo-in-16-04-lts